# Is dummy page '/#' in Laravel safe?

Tags: laravel-4

Using Laravel 4.1.30

Scenario: I got a home page and a link. When someone click the link the user is taken to different pages depending on his/her level.

Programming procedure: On the link at template you point on a unique route. The route then points to a controller. The controller test the level of user then gets to the proper pages.

Currently, since there is no chance for the controller to direct it to that URL, I use a '/#' as link to the URL of Route.

Question: Is this safe and bug free?

Here is my Route code:

```
Route::get('/#',array(
   'as'   => 'go-find-default-page'
   'uses' => 'MyController'
));
```

I do not want to create a dummy page a user will never use.

Comment: As far as I know the `#` is never passed to the server and is only used by the browser to point to an anchor (or as a query-string for a Javascript client-side app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5), clients (i.e. web browsers for example) are not supposed to send URI-fragments (this is the part of the URL following the `#` sign) to servers when they retrieve a document. Therefore, you cannot use `/#` as a route.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use dummy page instead